# Ads in other languages

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

This came up for me in Jobs:

[image]

I cannot read or write Arabic, but somehow because it's remote it showed it to me. Should the employer be providing an English translation when they create the job ad? This way the advertisement could be shown in English?

I just don't see any benefit in showing this to most folks in the US at least.

Comment: If the job requires you to speak the language that it was posted in I am not sure that posting it also in English would help.

Comment: Well ya thats my point - do we need this sort of ad or should it be targeted to that country or countries who speak AR?

Comment: People outside of a country can speak the language so there is no reason to limit it by country/region just for language reasons.

Comment: We could use, I don't know, the language(s) the user has defined in the browser. You know, like [HTTP says we can do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language)?

Comment: Do they speak Arabic in Iran? I suspect it's Farsi.

Comment: Sorry meant farsi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! That particular ad was targeted at visitors in Teheran, Iran, but due to a bug, we weren't applying that filter.

This should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting topic, I would hazard a guess to answer appropriately we would need to have additional data points and address what might be held as common assumptions.

***Perhaps the largest implied assumption:***

- *It won't benefit most folks in the US implies that most members of SO are from the United states and are the audience for seeing the advertisement.*

My personal opinion is that it seems that while US makes up a very large portion of the community there is an huge portion that is international.  Especially when it comes to the questions from the new learners the posts often suggest English as second language.

***Maybe another assumption***

- *People seeking remote work are primarily US based?*

While it may not make since for some of us in the US to see, I would hazard a guess that a very significant portion of the people seeking remote positions are outside the US.  So could it be argued that one audience vs another is a minority?

***Should the company provide an English Translation?***

I think I agree with the others if the language is a requirement for the work then providing an English translation would actually be a disservice to the company.  However giving the ability to provide multiple translations could be a huge benefit if multiple languages would be accepted.

***Does it benefit the company?***

Sure it could if they land an applicant that they hire assuming that the ad will be shown to international members as well as US members.

***Does StackOverflow Benefit?***

Somebody got paid somewhere.

***Did you or I Benefit?***

No I have no idea what that language even is.

***Is there perhaps a more meaningful method of presenting ads for the company and the candidate?***

Sure using IP address to understand geolocation, globalization settings... that's a larger topic :)

Edit adding thanks to Nathan check out the geography maps in section 1:

https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016

It shows that while the US is the largest individual segment it doesn't represent half of the overall traffic and developers in the world.

Comment: hum aren't job ads already shown by location ? The problem here is that the job is remote, so location should not be an issue.

Comment: @Kaiido good point on the remote, but I would guess using IP for geolocation would take care of that so would cover that issue as well.  But I would also hazard a guess that a very significant people seeing "remote" work are actually not based in the US

Comment: Never mind your opinion about non-US dev share; the [SO survey](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016) (section I) makes it clear with hard data that the US is an admittedly big fish in a rather large pond.

Comment: @NathanTuggy interesting link, but I would interpret the findings completely different than you.  US shows 3.8 mil professional developers.  India has 1.8, Uk 800K, German 750K, China 390K, Italy 270K.  That's 4 mil in 5 countries and there are 167 more countries so that to me says while US is the largest 1 segment that 1 segment doesn't represent even half.  Looking at monthly visits is way more staggering US is 46.5 million visits and India alone is nearly 26 million visitors

Comment: @Matt: That's exactly what I said. The opening clause was just to point out that opinion isn't worth much, especially when actual supporting data is readily available.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I read your first comment completely opposite of what you intended then, anyway thanks for the link very interesting!  I have really only been on here a few months now so still lots to learn about some of it cheers.